# Using forall() in extracting String from Option[String] in scala

Tags: scala, forall

I don't understand when forAll deals with None values.

```
def areTheyEqual(x: Option[String], y: String) = {
    if (x.forall(_ == y)) {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

When I call the function:
`areTheyEqual(None, "hello")` this returns true, when I expect this to be false since they are not equal. Please help. Why is it like this?

Edit:

To solve this, I changed the if statement to:
`if (x.nonEmpty && x.forall(_ == y))`
But I still want to know why it returned true without the `x.nonEmpty` condition.

Comment: If you think of a Some as a list with a single element and None as a list with 0 elements (which they’re not), that might help

Comment: BTW `if (foo) true else false` is redundant, you can just return `foo`.

Comment: This is how `forall` def looks like `final def forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = isEmpty || p(this.get)`. So, if it is empty and that means a None eitherway, it will return true, otherwise will test the predicate. From the documentation                                              ` /** Returns true if this option is empty '''or''' the predicate`
   `* $p returns true when applied to this $option's value.`
   `*`
   `* This is equivalent to:`
  ` * option match {`
  ` *   case Some(x) => p(x)`
   `*   case None    => true`
 ` * }`
  `*/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `forall` method checks whether all of the objects in the collection satisfy some predicate. So what does it mean when  it returns `false`? Logically, it must mean that there is an element in the collection where the predicate isn't true. So does `None` contain an element where the predicate isn't true? Obviously not, because it doesn't contain any element at all. Hence it would be wrong for `forall` to return `false` in that case. So it all makes sense.

The `exists` method on the other hand will return `false` if the `Option` is empty.